# Unload data from Redshift to S3 using Airflow

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, airflow

I would like to unload data from the Redshift db to an S3 bucket, which would later be used to copy into another database. I have written my DAG as below:

```
from airflow.operators import RedshiftToS3Transfer
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG

default_args = {
  'owner': 'me',
  'start_date': datetime.today(),
  'max_active_runs': 1,
}

dag = DAG(dag_id='redshift_S3',
  default_args=default_args,
  schedule_interval="@once",
  catchup=False
)

unload_to_S3 = RedshiftToS3Transfer(
  task_id='unload_to_S3',
  schema='schema_name',
  table='table_name',
  s3_bucket='bucket_name',
  s3_key='s3_key',
  redshift_conn_id='redshift',
  aws_conn_id='my_s3_conn',
  dag=dag
)
```

But I get an error "Broken DAG: cannot import name 'RedshiftToS3Transfer' from 'airflow.operators' (unknown location)". Any idea on how to import the RedshiftToS3Transfer would be of help.

Comment: Hi, if you're answering your own question, please put it as an answer rather than an update to the question. This makes it clear this question has been answered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The right way to import this is

from airflow.operators.redshift_to_s3_operator import RedshiftToS3Transfer